# The proof of $H(x)=\int _{(-\infty,x)}h(y)dy$ with $h(y)\ge 0$ then $E(H(X))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(y)P(X\ge y)dy$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The proof

If $H(x)=\int _{(-\infty,x)}h(y)dy$ with $h(y)\ge 0$, then $E(H(X))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(y)P(X\ge y)dy$

And the application of the special case $H(x)=exp(\theta x)$ with $\theta >0$

My proof is as below:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(y)P(X\ge y)dy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_\Omega h(y)I(X\ge y)dPdy=\int_\Omega\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(y)I(X\ge y)dydP=\int_\Omega\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(y)I(X\ge y)dydP=\int_\Omega\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(y)I(X(w)\ge y)dyPdw=\int_\Omega\int_{I(y\leq X(w))} h(y)dyPdw$=E(h(X))

As for the special case $H(x)=exp(\theta x)$ with $\theta>0$

$H(x)=\int_{(-\infty,x]}exp(\theta x)\theta dx$

$E(H(X))=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}exp(\theta y)\theta P(X\ge y)dx$

My question is how to verify the equation using this special example。

Does it mean if I know the distribution of X,  I can calculate $E(H(X))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(y)P(X\ge y)dy$

Comment: What does $E(H(x))$ mean? $H(x)$ is not a random variable. Do you mean $E(H(X))?$

Comment: You have confused your $dx$ and $dy$ in a few places.

Comment: And the last equation should be $E(H(X))=\dots$ not $E(h(X))=\dots,$ no?

Comment: I will verify it soon, Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have changes the statement. Can you give me some suggestion?  Many thanks!

Comment: Where did you come across this equality? I do not believe it is true.

Comment: I have already get it. It is from an exercise. I will explain it.

Comment: Does it mean if I know the distribution of X,  I can calculate $E(H(X))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(y)P(X\ge y)dy$